# Firebase Auth, after logging a user from react client, how do I verify user is legitimate within my other api?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase authentication to sign up and login users for my react website, but after that, how do I ensure that actions made from *my* nodejs api (for instance creating/modifying articles) are from that logged-in user. Here's a situation:

- User logs in on my website, the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method is called directly by the client within react (I can't use that method on my api since it asks for the raw password and I don't want to be sending that across the web, though I could save a salt on my db and hash the password, etc. but the reason I'm using firebase auth is to avoid having to be hashing passwords and maintaining salts on my db)
- User is confirmed logged in
- User starts to create an article
- They submit the created article, react verifies they are logged in with `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`
- Article data is sent to my api, for instance `POST somehost.com/myapi/article/create/` with the article data in the body
- My api receives the request and saves the article to my database

The problem I see here is that I don't see a way to send credentials to `somehost.com/myapi/article/create/` in order to verify the user before entering the article into my db, since all signup/login is done within react and firebase's auth functions don't return anything I can send to my api to verify, so essentially anyone can call that endpoint and flood my database with junk.

I would like to be able to login the user within react, but then verify the user is legit within *my* api for all calls the user makes to it before it sends anything to the db. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your Firebase client app communicates with a custom backend server, you might need to identify the currently signed-in user on that server. To do so securely, after a successful sign-in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the integrity and authenticity of the ID token and retrieve the uid from it. You can use the uid transmitted in this way to securely identify the currently signed-in user on your server.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens